# Amazon Alexa: AMAZON.DATE to Java Date/Duration

Tags: java, iso8601

If I use AMAZON.DATE as a slot type, the user is able to input all kind of dates. Stating from the documentation:
"2015-12", "2017-WI" (for winter of 2017) or "2015-W48-WE" (for weekend of week 48 of 2015). I want to parse these dates into Java dates/durations and I wonder how to achieve this.

Is there a Java library that takes a date like "2015-12" and returns two dates or a date and a duration?
I can see a lot of potential problems like time zone handling or ambiguous dates, but I hope this is a common problem.

I could write a parser to save it as two Dates, one for the beginning of the month and one for the end of the month. Or a date for the beginning and a duration, but this seems like a lot of overhead to comply with ISO 8601.

Comment: `YearMonth.parse("2015-12")` ?

Comment: What about "2015-W48-WE"? I would need a different parsing function for every possible income 'type'.

Comment: Have you found a library or did you implemented it yourself?

Comment: Did you ever find a java function that parses AMAZON.DATE into a java date?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's [Calendar Reader](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-calendar-reader) skill sample contains [a JavaScript AMAZON.DATE parser](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-calendar-reader/blob/master/src/index.js#L292) that should be fairly easy to convert to other languages.  It takes the slot value and returns a JavaScript Date object.  According to the comments, it handles all of the idiomatic date formats.

```
// Utterances that map to the weekend for a specific week (such as 'this weekend') convert to a date indicating the week number and weekend: 2015-W49-WE.
// Utterances that map to a month, but not a specific day (such as 'next month', or 'December') convert to a date with just the year and month: 2015-12.
// Utterances that map to a year (such as 'next year') convert to a date containing just the year: 2016.
// Utterances that map to a decade convert to a date indicating the decade: 201X.
// Utterances that map to a season (such as 'next winter') convert to a date with the year and a season indicator: winter: WI, spring: SP, summer: SU, fall: FA)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been going crazy trying to find an example of someone doing this. Turns out you just have to parse it out manually anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use The Amazon date parser in Nodejs for converting it.

The amazon-date-parser is an useful npm package (more info here). It converts the AMAZON.DATE slot value to a JS object composed by a startDate and an endDate i.e.:

```
var AmazonDateParser = require('amazon-date-parser');
var date = new AmazonDateParser('2017-W48');
console.log(date);
```

Comment: This is not a JS question.